# Using RubyMine, how do I fix "Get available generators script executes with errors" warning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine, thor

In RubyMine 2017.1 (and maybe earlier), the "Messages" Tool Window, opens with the title "Messages  Get available generators list" and displays

```
Warning:Get available generators script executes with errors:
Warning:Expected string default value for '--serializer'; got true (boolean)
```

This happens each time I open the project, but also after certain events.

Comment: I have the almost same issue!
My error message is like this.  
  
`/path_to_project/bin/rails` . 
`Warning:Get available generators script executes with errors:` . 
`Warning:Expected boolean default value for '--markerb'; got :erb (string)`

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a fix at this time, but a work-around is to downgrade the `thor` gem from `0.19.4` to `0.19.1`.

```
gem 'thor', '0.19.4'
```

and

```
bundle update thor
```

This appears to be expected behavior in thor > 0.19.1, and the gems that are using thor are expected to fix the problems with invalid parameters.  See https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/issues/538

Comment: I don't use the thor gem, but I have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In Rubymine go to `Help` > `Find Actions`
Or press `Ctrl + Shift + A`
Then toggle the `Rails Generators Spring pre-loader` to turn it off as marked in the picture:
[image]

Have a good sleep :)